# C++ Should this type satisfy std::is_copy_assignable?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

With following code:

```
namespace _Detail
{
    struct _HasCopyAssignment
    {
        template <typename _Type>
        static auto test(_Type&& var) -> decltype(var = var, std::true_type());
        static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    };
}

template <typename _Type>
struct HasCopyAssignment : public decltype(_Detail::_HasCopyAssignment::test(std::declval<_Type>()))
{};
```

And this test type:

```
struct B
{
    B& operator=(B&);
};
```

my `HasCopyAssignment<B>::value` evaluates to `true`, but `<type_traits>` test for `is_copy_assignable<B>::value` in GCC standard lib implementation is `false`. Should object be considered copy assignable if it's copy assignment operator take a non-const reference as parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libstdc++ is correct as marking this as not `std::is_copy_assignable`. Per C++14 20.10.4.3 table 49, `is_copy_assignable` is defined as:

> For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as `is_assignable<T, const T&>::value`, otherwise `false`.

This means that the type trait `std::is_copy_assignable<T>` means "`T` can be assigned into with a `const T&` argument." Which your class cannot.

Comment: @AlexanderBily Edited to match; yes, the answer is identical.